# How to summarize total number in an array object

Tags: javascript

```js
const dataAll = [ {id: 1, slp: { total: '3' }},{id: 2, slp: { total: '6' }},{id: 3, slp: { total: '5' }} ]

const res = dataAll.map((singleData) => singleData.data.slp.total);
const theres = JSON.stringify(res);
console.log(theres);
```

How can I add up all the total numbers from the array above?
so I can get the total of 3 + 6 + 5 = 14

and to get a number of the total number of an array in .length total of 3 example

Comment: use reduce() for such use-cases. map() works on all elements of the array and transforms the individual elements, reduce() works on computing something out of the array and returning a single element ( number/object etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add them using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and take the length as `dataAll.length`

```js
const dataAll = [
  { id: 1, slp: { total: "3" } },
  { id: 2, slp: { total: "6" } },
  { id: 3, slp: { total: "5" } },
];

const total = dataAll.reduce((acc, curr) => +curr.slp.total + acc, 0);
const length = dataAll.length;

console.log(total, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const dataAll = [{ id: 1, slp: { total: '3' } }, { id: 2, slp: { total: '6' } }, { id: 3, slp: { total: '5' } }]
let total = 0
dataAll.map((singleData)=>{
    total += parseInt(singleData.slp.total)
})
//Use whatever hook you need here to store the total value
setTotalHook(total, dataAll.length)
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to sum up values in an array.

```js
const dataAll = [ {id: 1, slp: { total: '3' }},{id: 2, slp: { total: '6' }},{id: 3, slp: { total: '5' }} ]

const res = dataAll.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + parseInt(a.slp.total), 0); 
const theres = JSON.stringify(res);
console.log(theres);
```

Answer (score 0):

For length just check the length property of the array.

To sum up the totals you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array of objects and add the value of `total` to the accumulator (initially set to zero) on each iteration. Note: you need to coerce that value to a number.

```js
const data = [ {id: 1, slp: { total: '3' }},{id: 2, slp: { total: '6' }},{id: 3, slp: { total: '5' }} ];

const sum = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Coerce the string value to a number
  // and add it to the accumulator
  return acc + Number(c.slp.total);
}, 0);

console.log(`Length: ${data.length}`);
console.log(`Sum: ${sum}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const dataAll = [ {id: 1, slp: { total: '3' }},{id: 2, slp: { total: '6' }},{id: 3, slp: { total: '5' }} ]
const sum = dataAll.reduce(((total, b) => total + parseInt(b.slp.total, 10)), 0);
const totalElements = dataAll.length;
console.log(sum, totalElements)
```